# NodeCreationFailure-> Unhealthy nodes in the kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I have created a Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service in US East (Ohio)us-east-2 region. After cluster setup I have created Fargate profile which is done successfully. Now I am trying to Add a Node group but its ends with showing error "**NodeCreationFailure Unhealthy nodes in the kubernetes cluster**" issue. What's the reason?

Comment: I am not familiar with this, but your question may need more detail to get a response :/. Enough detail for others to replicate your issue

Answer (score 11):

your nodes are unable to register with your Amazon EKS cluster.
A quick and dirty solution consists in adding  AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy to the worker nodegroup role.
If that's solve the problem please be aware that the recommended approach is instead:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-iam-role.html

Comment: Nice. This worked for me. Should be the accepted answer. Thanks Clemente